# Identify the current value between \$(3 + j4) \Omega\$

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I have a following circuit described below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ5WdZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Source has \$u = 10 \angle{0^{\circ}}\$ and the resistance of the circuit is \$R_1 = 20 \Omega \text{, } R_2 = 10 \Omega \text{, } R_3 = 3 \Omega \text{, } X_{L_1} = 5 \Omega \text{, } X_{L_2} = 2.5 \Omega \text{, } X_{L_3} = 4 \Omega \text{, }\$

As I analyze the circuit, I find that the current through the branch of \$R_3 \text{ and } L_3\$ is **0 (A)** but I don't know why. How to prove by calculating on this circuit?

Comment: Do you know the balance condition of a bridge?

Comment: Did you mean \$X_L=\text{x}\;\Omega\$, or \$L=\text{x}\;\text{H}\$? Anyway, you have a bridge there, some special considerents may apply.

Comment: @Chu What is that condition? I don't know about it

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Oh I see, I will correct it now

Comment: Try a search engine 'wheatstone bridge'.

Comment: @Chu I have tried to search but I can not find the condition of balance of bridge circuit here

Comment: Try harder.....

Comment: Please show us the working you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

A few hints: -

Forget about R3 and L3 and regard them as open circuit then, forget about L1 and L2 being inductors and regard them as being resistors. Then ask yourself this: -

[image]

You can even replace the sine source with a battery if you want. Same question in red.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem because you already have a very good answer by [@Andyaka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka). When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPeQhV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5\\
\\
0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4+\text{I}_6
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also know that \$\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4=\text{V}_\text{i}\$.

Now, we can set-up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{0 == I1 + I3 + I5, I3 == I2 + I4, I6 == I2 + I5, 
   0 == I1 + I4 + I6, I1 == (V2 - V1)/R1, I1 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (V2 - V3)/R3, I4 == V3/R4, I5 == (V2 - V4)/R5, I6 == V4/R6, 
   V3 - V4 == Vi}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R4 R5 - R3 R6) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 +
     R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6), 
  I2 -> -((((R3 + R4) (R5 + R6) + R1 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R6) + 
       R2 (R3 + R4 + R5 + R6)) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + 
        R3) R4 R5 + 
     R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6)), 
  I3 -> -(((R4 (R1 + R2 + R5) + (R1 + R2 + R4) R6) Vi)/((R1 + 
        R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
     R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6)), 
  I4 -> ((R1 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R5) + 
      R3 (R5 + R6)) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
    R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6), 
  I5 -> (((R1 + R2) R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R6) Vi)/((R1 + 
       R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
    R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6), 
  I6 -> -((((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5) Vi)/((R1 + 
        R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
     R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6)), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R4 R5 - 
      R3 R6) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
    R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6), 
  V2 -> ((R1 + R2) (R4 R5 - 
      R3 R6) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
    R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6), 
  V3 -> (R4 (R1 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R5) + 
      R3 (R5 + R6)) Vi)/((R1 + R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
    R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6), 
  V4 -> -((((R1 + R2) R3 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5) R6 Vi)/((R1 + 
        R2) R3 R4 + (R1 + R2 + R3) R4 R5 + 
     R3 (R1 + R2 + R4) R6 + (R1 + R2 + R3 + R4) R5 R6))}}
```

So, we can see that:

$$\displaystyle\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{R}_4\text{R}_5-\text{R}_3\text{R}_6\right)}{\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_6\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)+\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_6\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\right)}\tag3$$

> Now, what happends when \$\text{R}_4\text{R}_5=\text{R}_3\text{R}_6\$ (what is the case in your circuit)?